# Python class inheritance

Tags: python, class

I have this code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
       print " A"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print "B"
x=B()
print "Done"
```

the result is: "B" gets printed 
why does it not print "A", eventhough class B inheritance A

Comment: Because you're overriding the __init__ method?

Comment: Python doesn't automatically call the superclass constructor for you; you need to explicitly call it yourself. The fact that this just passes silently is one of the design flaws of Python's class system implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use A's `__init__` while also using B's `__init__`, then try:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
       print " A"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        print "B"
x=B() 
print "Done"
```

Or, if you would prefer not to mention the superclass by name:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
       print " A"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print "B"
x=B()
print "Done"
```

Both of these produce the output:

```
 A
B
Done
```

Comment: Never use `super(self.__class__, self)`. It fails as soon as you make a descendant of `B` and `self.__class__` isn't `B` any more.